# Adding multiple filetypes to my Python script

Tags: python

I've created a script that moves files in my downloads folder into the trashbin.

The script works but only for one file type. If I add another in I get the following error:

```py
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

```
import os
import send2trash

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk('/Users/adamchapman/Downloads'):

    for file in files: 
        if file.endswith ('.xlsx', '.csv'):
            path = os.path.join(folder,file)

            print:('deleted:', path)

            send2trash.send2trash(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.endswith` can take either a single suffix string or a *tuple* of suffix strings to look for:

> Return `True` if the string ends with the specified *suffix*, otherwise return `False`. *suffix* can also be a tuple of suffixes to look for.

The second parameter is the index at which to start the search, hence the odd error: you're asking Python to see if the string ends with `.xlsx`, but only after the index `.csv`.

So the call should be

```
if file.endswith(('.xlsx', '.csv')):
```

Alternatively, you can use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) and check if the extension is in a known set e.g.

```py
TRASH = {'.xlsx', '.csv'}

[...]

_, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
if ext in TRASH:
    [...]
```

The disadvantage is that it's a bit less flowing, the advantage is that it should be a bit more reliable when dealing with the odd dotfile.

Even better is [`pathlib.Path.suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix) which just hands you the extension (with the same semantics as `splitext`), though it might not be great on a lone file so you may want to first compute the full path upfront:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import send2trash

TRASH = {'.xlsx', '.csv'}

for folder, _, files in os.walk('/Users/adamchapman/Downloads'):
    for path in map(Path(folder).joinpath, files): 
        if path.suffix in TRASH:
            print('deleted:', path)

            send2trash.send2trash(path) # may or may not need to explicitly stringify `Trash`.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Makes sense and will bear this in mind when using the .endswith function in the future

Answer (score -2):

.endswith() only takes one suffix.
Use the **or** keyword.

```
for file in files: 
    if file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.csv'):
        path = os.path.join(folder,file)

        print:('deleted:', path)

        send2trash.send2trash(path)
```

Comment: `endswith` can take a tuple of suffixes to check for multiple suffixes at the same time.